# Can't unsubscribe from JavaScript event

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

I'm trying to use this piece of JavaScript to listen for keystrokes in a Blazor application.
It works fine by declaring a static method (`JsKeyDown`) on the page I would like to receive and handle the input on and subscribing to it using `await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("JsFunctions.AddKeyboardListenerEvent");` but I would also need to be able to unregister from the event.
Since I have no clue when it comes to JS I was hoping someone could help me modify this from a what I believe to be an anonymous function that is being used to subscribe to the event to one that can also be used to unsubscribe e.g. `RemoveKeyboardListenerEvent`.

```
window.JsFunctions = {
    AddKeyboardListenerEvent: function (_) {
        let serializeEvent = function (e) {
            if (e) {
                return {
                    key: e.key,
                    code: e.keyCode.toString(),
                    location: e.location,
                    repeat: e.repeat,
                    ctrlKey: e.ctrlKey,
                    shiftKey: e.shiftKey,
                    altKey: e.altKey,
                    metaKey: e.metaKey,
                    type: e.type
                };
            }
        };
        
        window.document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('ClassName', 'JsKeyDown', serializeEvent(e))
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: you;d use `.removeEventListener` - but your function can't be anonymous when you `.addEventListener`

Comment: You can use abort controller for that